# Default value assigned when pressing Enter

Tags: go, input

I want a default value to be assigned when pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> without giving one.

From my experience *Go Playground* doesn't handle fmt.Scan inputs, so I quote the code here:
(If it's possible, tell me how please!)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t := 0
    fmt.Print("seconds? ")
    fmt.Scan(&t)
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(t) * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("in", t)
}
```

I've initialized the value of `t` to `0` but when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> without giving a value the program waits until I give some value. I'm not interested in error checking (if that's possible). I just want the code to accept a single <kbd>Enter</kbd> press, as `0` <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use [`fmt.Scanln()`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Scanln) instead of [`fmt.Scan()`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Scan):

```
fmt.Scanln(&t)
```

Quoting from `fmt.Scanln()`:

> Scanln is similar to Scan, but **stops scanning at a newline** and after the final item there must be a newline or EOF.

On the other hand, `fmt.Scan()` does not stop at a newline, but:

> Scan scans text read from standard input, storing successive space-separated values into successive arguments. **Newlines count as space.**

In general I suggest to use [`bufio.Scanner`](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#Scanner) to read input by lines, and do whatever you want to with the lines (check if its empty, or parse it the way you want). [`bufio.NewScanner()`](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#NewScanner) allows you to use a (predefined) string as the source (combined with [`strings.NewReader()`](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#NewReader)–for easy testing) or pass `os.Stdin` if you want to read user input.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bufio.Reader`

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var t int

    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("seconds? ")
    for {
        tStr, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
        tStr = strings.TrimSpace(tStr)

        t, err = strconv.Atoi(tStr)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("invalid input, please write a number")
            continue
        }
        break
    }

    time.Sleep(time.Duration(t) * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("in", t)
}
```